# Bitmap get croped when setting to Image inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Scrollable Imageview, Image will be inside the scrollview in framelayout, and that layout will have fix size and image will be scrolled.

So When runtime changing size of framelayout, affecting bitmap and get crop from the bottom and the size of framelayout changed and also imageview size.

**Only the problem with the bitmap croped**

Layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Programatically changing the framelayout like

```
private void changeSizeOfImage(int width,int height){
    mImageViewImage.destroyDrawingCache();
    mImageViewImage.buildDrawingCache();
    mFrameLayoutImageMain.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));

        if (bitmap != null) {
            mImageViewImage.setImageBitmap(null);
            mImageViewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting ImageView height as wrap_content

Comment: then also it is same

Comment: change the `scaleType` to `centerInside`

Comment: @Waqas top portion of image is croped and bottom showing empty space